# htaccess rewrite condition / find pattern in file names

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want certain images in a folder to be watermarked. I got the following htaccess-chunk which is working well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/media/image/thumbnail/(.*)([gif|jpe?g|png|bmp])$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /watermark/watermark.php?src=$1 [L]
```

However I only want to watermark the bigger thumbnails. There is a naming convention in our system which adds the dimensions of an image to the file name. A typical name would be:

img1_285x255.png

So how would I have to change the .htaccess in order to access files whose names end with "285x255.png" for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `So how would I have to change the .htaccess in order to access files whose names end with "285x255.png" for example?`

You can do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?285x255\.png)$ /watermark/watermark.php?src=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Just one line! :p Works like a charm! Thank you very much!!! And I promise, once this project is done I will finally do some homework and learn more about .htaccess' syntax

Comment: You're welcome. These rules are mostly about playing with regex so it's really fun.